# Is there a way to put a hyperlink in a cell of a table?

Tags: support, formatting, markdown

I have the following table. I'd like to use the hyperlinked dates which follow the table inside the table. Is this possible?

---

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|l|}\hline
Year(s) & page & value \\ \hline
1969 & 50(footnote) & 6.022\,52(7)\times 10^{23}\\ \hline
1973 & 25 (17.3) & 6.022\,176(97) \times 10^{23} \\ \hline
1986 & 6 & 6.022\,136\,7(36) \times 10^{23}\\ \hline
1998 & 6 & 6.022\,141\,99(47)\times 10^{23}\\ \hline
2002 & 6 & 6.022\,141\,5(10)\times 10^{23} \\ \hline
2006 & 7 & 6.022\,141\,79(30)\times 10^{23} \\ \hline
2010 & 5 & 6.022\,141\,29(27) \times10^{23} \\ \hline
2014 & 5 & 6.022\,140\,857(74)\times 10^{23} \\ \hline
2018 & 5 & 6.022\,140\,76\mathrm{(exact)}\times10^{23} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

[1969 link](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/1969RMP.pdf#page=50) - error calculated by multiplying 11 ppm times value

[1973 link](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/1973JPCRD.pdf#page=25)

[1986 link](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/codata86.pdf#page=6)

[2002 link](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/all_2002.pdf#page=6)

[2006 link](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/all_2006.pdf#page=7)

[2010 link](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/all_2010.pdf#page=5)

[2014 link](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/all_2014.pdf#page=5)

[2018 Link](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Category?view=pdf&All+values.x=72&All+values.y=9#page=5) - exact by new definition of constant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use the brand [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/295232), i.e. use Markdown tables instead of LaTeX. For example:

```
|Year|Value|
|:--:|-----|
| [1969](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/1969RMP.pdf#page=50) | 6.022 52(7) &times; 10<sup>23</sup> |
| [1973](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/1973JPCRD.pdf#page=25) | $6.022\, 176(97) \times 10^{23}$ |
```

produces

| Year | Value |
| --- | --- |
| [1969](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/1969RMP.pdf#page=50) | 6.022 52(7) × 10<sup>23</sup> |
| [1973](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/1973JPCRD.pdf#page=25) | $6.022\, 176(97) \times 10^{23}$ |

You can see the table supports MathJax as well, if you need it.